# RAILS: SEARCH AND MODIFY COLUMN IN MODEL WITH PARAM PASSING FROM FORM

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Please i have an problem: my  form is that

```
<%=form_for :abbonamentos, url: url_for( :controller => :abbonamentos, :action => :edit) do |f| %>

            <div class="field">
              <%= f.label :id%><br />
              <%= f.text_field :id%>
            </div> 
        <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit %>
          </div> 
        <% end %>


        and my controller is that:


          def edit
                 id = params[:abbonamentos][:id]
                @b = Abbonamento.find_by_id(id)
                @user = current_user
                a=Abbonamento.find_by(user_id: @user.id)


            if a and @b
                a.update_column(:stato_ingresso, (a.stato_ingresso-1))
                @stato =  a.stato_ingresso
                flash[:success] = "Abbonamento used"
                redirect_to :scegli_posti
            else
                    flash.now[:error] = "Non ha abbonamento lo deve acquistare."
            end
          end
```

I want to verify if the params id exist in the model Abbonamento...When i try i have error like this: 
            NoMethodError in AbbonamentosController#edit
            undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Thank you

Please may be I can not explain myself well. In the research I want to do I suppose the user is already registered in the Abbonamento table with his id (user_id). When the user registers in the table abbonamento, its registration that will be returned is abbonamento_id which can be 1 or 2 . When he wants to use the subscription, you will have to insert the code (abbonamento_id) there so that the application can check if the code is right or wrong before making an action. If this is true the application will make an action otherwise it will be another. 
It is in fact that I would realize with rails. thank you

```
Started POST "/usa_abbonamento" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-30 14:29:00 +0200
Processing by AbbonamentosController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8Ydr6NPDkynPQd9zo42vgxNIsNSwz4SPkI0JNzfc4lQ=", "abbonamentos"=>{"id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Save Abbonamentos"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = 'c2bc8173fcb2c5cce4b2606962859049830be6aa' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mAbbonamento Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "abbonamentos".* FROM "abbonamentos" WHERE "abbonamentos"."user_id" = 1[0m
  [1m[35mAbbonamento Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT "abbonamentos".* FROM "abbonamentos" WHERE "abbonamentos"."id" IS NULL
  Rendered abbonamentos/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (3.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 47ms (Views: 40.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

Comment: kindly post the actual params you are sending to the edit action.

Comment: You can use `find_or_initialize_by_id(id)` or `find_or_create_by_id` to initialise a row if it does not exist.

Comment: @user3588663 I want to check the params, what the request actually is sending.

Comment: Please i have a same error: NoMethodError in AbbonamentosController#edit
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Kindly post the parameters this method is receiving

Comment: See the problem is that i understood what you want to do, i think the parameter string the action is receiving is not correct, hence the error undefined method '[]' for nil class, that is why i want you to post the parameters this action is actually receiving

Comment: class Abbonamento < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

Comment: class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :abbonamento
end

Comment: Well I don't understand what you guyz discussed above. I would suggest you to share the entire server log with the error info, so we can see exactly on which line and in which file you received the error.

Comment: Kirti i put as part of the log we are interested in the question above. Thx

Comment: You missed the actual error log which tells you `NoMethodError in AbbonamentosController#edit undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`and  gives a stacktrace.

Comment: @Babar SO is English Board. Please refrain from using other language. Thanks.

Comment: @KirtiThorat He can not speak English... I am only trying to help

Comment: @user3588663 Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller code as,

```
     def edit
             id = params[:abbonamentos][:id]
            @b = Abbonamento.where(:id => id)
            @user = current_user
            a=Abbonamento.where(:user_id => @user.id)


        if a.present? and @b.present?
            a.update_column(:stato_ingresso, (a.stato_ingresso-1))
            @stato =  a.stato_ingresso
            flash[:success] = "Abbonamento used"
            redirect_to :scegli_posti
        else
                flash.now[:error] = "Non ha abbonamento lo deve acquistare."
        end
      end
```

You can make use of `present?` or `blank?` method to check if row exists.

Comment: Please i try that but error like this: NoMethodError in AbbonamentosController#edit
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass